# The clock with a note

Tags: riddle

I bought a regular analog clock, and it came with a note saying:

> Take yourself a picture
> Around a special time
> And though you will not hear my tick
> You'll see it just fine

How can this be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "special time" is

> something like 10:05,

a time at which

> the hour and minute hands of the clock form a tick shape: $\checkmark$.

Thus,

> you can't hear the "tick" of the clock, but you can see the *tick*.

Comment: Sadly the symbol you've used doesn't display consistently on Chrome for Android.

Comment: @rybo111 I'm not sure why, since it should be rendered using PSE's built-in thing like other mathematical symbols. Can you see other MathJax rendering here without issues? (And whoops, deleted my spoilery comment.)

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug with spoilers? Kinda weird as if I post a comment it suddenly displays...